# User Account Control for Metro-style apps?

Tags: windows-8, uac, windows-store-app

Are there any changes in UAC (User Account Control) for Metro-style applications in Windows 8?

Metro-style applications come from Windows Store only and they should have already passed a lot of security checks - shouldn't UAC be more forgiving for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UAC forces you to grant approval before running things with administrative privileges.

Modern UI apps cannot have any administrative privileges, so UAC does not apply.

Comment: Oh, metro apps can't be run with administrative privileges! That's harsh.

Comment: @VladimirSinenko - Not Really...Its not hard to design a desktop application that doesn't require it, most developers are just lazy, so they do stuff the incorrect way.

Comment: @VladimirSinenko: Modern UI apps have _far_ more restricitons than not having admin privileges.  They can't even interact directly with the underlying file system.  Modern UI apps have a completely different development model.

Answer (score 0):

The User Account Control doesn't perform checks on the safety of the software, but rather permission for elevation of authentication. Some apps will require entries to be created/modified in your registry as well as system folders. The user account that you're logged into does not necessarily have the access to write to these locations. However, you are presented with the option of continuing the installation/execution of the software through the elevation of privileges with User Access Control.

So it doesn't really have anything to do with the Metro apps or the security checks that it passes. Personally, I like knowing when something will be writing/accessing to system files and registry keys.